# How to make index of all files in directory, including subdirectiories and contents of ZIP files?

Tags: windows, zip

I need to make list of all files and folders in directory and its subdirectories, including contents of ZIP files.

Is there any program that can create nice list of contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinRAR can create HTML/text reports listing both non-compressed files as well as the contents of all supported archive formats:

[image: 1]

Besides this I am sure there are lots of directory listing utilities with ZIP support, such as [ExpPrint](http://www.jddesign.co.uk/products/expprint/expprint.htm) for example.

Answer (score 0):

On linux You have the find command that can find (and list) all files below a certain path.

```
find . -type f
```

for each zip-file found You could use

```
unzip -l thezipfile
```

in order to list contents. When encountering zipfiles inside zipfiles it may be a little more complicated though

Comment: Not helpful. I'm on windows and I have 500TB of data to index. I don't want to run unzip on all files.

Comment: unzip -l will list contents - not unzip the files to my  best of knowledge